# Delete last line of gz file

Tags: shell, files, gzip

I need to delete the last line of gz file without uncompressing.
The file has 500 lines.

How can I do that?

I have tried:

```
 gzip -dc "$files" | tail -500 | gzip -c > "$files".tmp
```

But It doesn´t works.

Comment: Do it step by step and then you can automate it in a single command.  `tail -500` will get you the last 500 lines which is obviously not what you're asking to do.  Perhaps `head` would be more suitable.  Note that your question also supposes that you don't uncompress it but you do (and have to).

Comment: zcat myfile.dat.gz | head -499 myfile.dat.gz > mynewokfile.dat.gz

It´s not working

Comment: In your 'I have tried' code, `gzip -d` actually *does* decompress, but your question says you cannot decompress. You can tell by looking at `man gzip` what the `-d` option is doing.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't modify a compressed file without decompressing it.

At the very least, to delete all text after the 499th line, you have to decompress the first 499 lines to find where the 499th line ends. If you want to delete the last line regardless of how many lines there are, you need to decompress the whole file to identify where the last line starts.

There is no shortcut because the file is compressed. The encoding of a character depends on all the previous characters — the basic principle of gzip compression is to use shorter bit sequences for character sequences that have been encountered previously, and slightly longer bit sequences for character sequences that haven't been encountered yet, thus yielding a smaller file when character sequences are repeated. There's no way to determine that a particular character is a line break without examining all the previous characters.

Your attempt, which decompresses the file, works on the decompressed stream, and recompresses to another file, is on the right track. You just need the correct command to truncate the file: `tail -500` keeps the last 500 lines, which isn't what you want. Use `head -n 499` to keep the first 499 lines, or `head -n -1` to remove the last line. Not all systems support a negative argument for `head`; if yours doesn't, you can use `sed '$d'` instead.

```
gunzip <"$file" | head -n -1 | gzip >"$file".tmp
mv -- "$file".tmp "$file"
```

Note that you can't directly write to file: <s>`gunzip <"$file" | … | gzip >"$file"`</s> would start overwriting the file while `gunzip` is still reading it. The commands in a pipeline are executed in parallel. While it's possible to avoid creating a temporary file, it's a bad idea, because any way to do that would result in a truncated file if the command is interrupted, so I won't discuss how to do it.

In theory, it would be possible to truncate a gzipped file by:

1. uncompressing it in memory to determine the position where you want to truncate it;
2. truncating the file to remove all data after the last character to keep;
3. overwrite the last few bytes to correctly encode the last character;
4. overwrite a few bytes at the beginning to reflect the new file size.

However this can't be done with standard tools, it would take some custom programming, and it would leave an invalid file if it was interrupted.

Answer (score 6):

Assuming from your example that decompressing to a stream is fine, but you want to avoid decompressing to a file.  You should be able to

```
gzip -cd "$files" | sed -e '$d' | gzip > "$files".tmp
```

using `sed` to go to the last line and delete it.

Comment: Hello , decompresssing is not fine

Comment: So your example is not on the path to an acceptable solution?  I think you're going to have a tough time modifying a gzip file without decompressing it

Comment: @ANOUK_prog:  What's the problem with the proposed solution which is similar to what you tried and deletes the last line as requested?

Comment: The only problem I see with decompressing (`gzip -d`) as @Eric and @ANOUK have shown in their code is that for a large file this could be slow, or if there were special metadata (surely not) in the original `.gz` file that would be excluded from the following `gzip` command.

Comment: @GeorgeBailey yeah, I only went with this approach because the original question suggested that decompressing the file, operating on it and recompressing was not acceptable, if preserving the metadata is important this will not do

Comment: Because of the way `gzip` formats the compressed data, a portion (page?) of the `.gz` file would have to be decompressed before removing the last line. Perhaps it is possible to do this without decompressing the entire file, but I am not sure. I would be interested to know if there is a utility that is capable of doing this. I don't know whether metadata even exists in a `.gz` file, but if so there should be an easy way to copy it.

Comment: @GeorgeBailey At least a little meta data is stored.  The man page includes "By default, gzip keeps the original file name and timestamp in the compressed  file." but yeah, something would have to decompress at least a little bit of the file to modify it I would think, and I'm not (yet) aware of anything that will modify the compressed file in place without full decompression

Answer (score 2):

You can use `zcat`.

```
zcat <file> | head -n <lines>
```

Only decompresses enough to stream those `n` lines.

Further reading: http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2009/05/zcat-zless-zgrep-zdiff-zcmp-zmore-gzip-file-operations-on-the-compressed-files/

Answer (score 1):

Building on @Eric Renouf's answer,(sorry, this is too long for a comment), to keep the original timestamp and filename metadata in the file, wrap it with:

```
gzip -cd "$file" | sed -e '$d' > "$file.tmp"
touch -r "$file" "$file.tmp"
# optionally keep the old file
# mv "$files" "$file.old"
mv "$file.tmp" "$file"
gzip "$file"
```

Or, since there's an uncompressed file just sitting there, use a `xz` instead of `gzip` to recompress it.  Better compression, and often faster.